# Delete data from firebase recycler view adapter without deleting in the database

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

That is it, can i remove a view from firebase recycler view adapter, but not deleting in the database?How?

```
 final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Game,GameViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Game, GameViewHolder>(
            Game.class,
            R.layout.row,
            GameViewHolder.class,
            mdatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(GameViewHolder viewHolder, Game model, final int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getGame_name());
            viewHolder.setJugado(model.getJugado());
            viewHolder.setCreator(model.getCreator_name());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't support this.  The whole point of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is that it stays in sync with the contents of the location that you originally gave it.  If something deletes data from the database, it will be automatically and unconditionally deleted from your adapter.

If you want this behavior, you will have to implement your own RecyclerView adapter, preferably one that does not use an active listeners to be notified of every change to the location of the data.  You would have to listen to the entire contents just once, then send that to an adapter to populate a RecyclerView.

Comment: Yes, after trying all afternoon I did that, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

And how about this in ViewHolder?

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That will delete the data but the place for the view will be still there, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You have to add this in your `GameViewHolder` class:

1. Create a function and get reference of your cardview
2. Create a layout params and Create an instance of the parent of your cardview then set the height and the width equals to 0

---

```
public  void  Remove() {
    cardView = mView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(0,0));
}
```

3. Use the function

---

```
viewHolder.remove();
```