# How to remove item from Firebase RecycleView without deleting from database?

Tags: java, android

I want to get data from firebase for an event. my event has some field, and I want to display the events that are going to happen. I did my date validation, but I don't know how not to display in my recycler the events I don't want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete data from firebase recycler view adapter without deleting in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925871/delete-data-from-firebase-recycler-view-adapter-without-deleting-in-the-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For firebase data in a recyclerView I would recommend using the [firebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html)

When using the default constructor you have to pass a query. You can customise your query to filter to your data.

example:

```
//custom query
Query q1 = reference.orderByChild("dateOfEvent").startAt("2019/02/12").endAt("2019/06/26");

//firebase recycler view adapter
 adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter<Object, ObjectViewHolder>(object.class, R.layout.object_list_item, ObjectViewHolder.class, q1) {
     public void populateViewHolder(ObjectViewHolder objectViewHolder, Object object) {
         objectViewHolder.nameText.setText(object.getFieldOne());
         objectViewHolder.messageText.setText(object.getFieldTwo());
     }
 };
 recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```